# Swift - macOS - Problem with Bundle App Path

Tags: swift, macos, path, .app, app-bundle

I made a Swift 5 macOS app, which loads some data from the folder where the .app file is located. Here is my code:

```
rutaApp = Bundle.main.bundlePath.replacingOccurrences(of: "/RetroMac.app", with: "")
```

it works ok in my computer. Then use Product -> Archive -> Copy App, and send my App.app file to an user who executes it.

For my surprise it crashes, saying that the path to the App.app file is "/private/var/folders/8g/7xj3ck2954ddhtrvzr89wklw0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/20D2ED2A-D864-4EFD-8310-7BD3476B4F44/d/" instead of "Documents/folderwheremyappis/"

Why does it happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you talking about a file on the app bundle or a file outside the bundle?

Comment: Outside the bundle

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `Bundle.main` and you should absolute not have some data file in the /Applications folder. Use [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) instead to access files.

Comment: I know what the problem is. Im distributing my app in a zip file, so app traslocation comes in. I dont really know how to solve it, but to distribute it in a .7z file....